# Symmetric orthogonal matrices with constant diagonal entries

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, matrices, real-algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\be}{\beta}
\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma}
\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}
\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}
\newcommand{\Si}{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\thh}{\theta}
\newcommand{\om}{\omega}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf E}} 
\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{\mathsf Var}} 
\renewcommand{\P}{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}
\newcommand{\ii}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf I}\{#1\}} 
\newcommand{\eD}{\overset{\text{D}}\to} 
\newcommand{\D}{\overset{\text{D}}=} 
\newcommand{\tsi}{\tilde\si}$

This question is a follow-up to the [previous question on symmetric matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306346/a-question-on-symmetric-matrices). Thanks to the responses by Christian Remling and Geoff Robinson to that question, the problem now becomes much more specific, as follows.

> Suppose that a symmetric matrix $M\in\R^{n\times n}$ is orthogonal or, equivalently, satisfies the condition $M^2=I_n$, where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Suppose also that all the diagonal entries of $M$ are equal to one another. Is it then true that $M$ is of the form $aI_n+b\,\de\de^T$, where $\de$ belongs to the set (say $\De_n$) of all $n\times 1$ column matrices with all entries from the set $\{-1,1\}$; $a\in\{-1,1\}$; and $b\in\{0,-2a/n\}$?

This is true for $n\in\{2,3\}$.

**Comment 1.** Let $\mathcal M_n$ denote the set of all matrices $M$ satisfying the stated conditions, that is, the set of all symmetric orthogonal matrices $M\in\R^{n\times n}$ with constant diagonal entries.
The actual problem here is to show that for each $M\in\mathcal M_n$ all the off-diagonal entries $M_{ij}$  of $M$ with $i\ne j$ are of the form $c\de_i\de_j$ for some real $c$ and some $\de\in\De_n$; it is then easy to specify the appropriate $a$ and $b$, given in the above question. So, it is enough to show that 
\begin{equation}
 \prod_{\de\in\De_n}\Big(\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\sum_{1\le k<\ell\le n}(M_{ij}\de_i\de_j-M_{k\ell}\de_k\de_\ell)^2\Big)=0, 
\end{equation}
which is how the cases the cases of $n\in\{2,3\}$ were verified.

**Comment 2.** More generally, even without the condition on the diagonal entries of $M$, it is enough to show that $M-aI_n$ is of rank $1$ for some real $a$.

Comment: what is an $n\times n$ column matrix?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam : Thank you for spotting the typo. It is now corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. A symmetric $M$ will satisfy $M^2=1$ if and only if the spectrum is contained in $\pm 1$, which is equivalent to $M=P-(1-P)=2P-1$ for some orthogonal projection $P$. Now you're asking if the extra condition that the diagonal is constant will give $P$ rank $1$ or $n-1$.

It's clear that this won't follow because we have such examples with $\textrm{rank }P=1$ for $n=2$ and can just take orthogonal sums of those for larger (even) $n$'s.

Comment: So, the cases of $n\in\{2,3\}$ are the only ones when the answer is yes. Turning to orthoprojectors is a nice idea.